# Optimise OpenGL ES 2.0 2D drawing using dirty rectangles

Tags: ios, ipad, optimization, rendering, opengl-es-2.0

Is it possible to optimise OpenGL ES 2.0 drawing by using dirty rectangles?

In my case, I have a 2D app that needs to draw a background texture (full screen on iPad), followed by the contents of several VBOs on each frame. The problem is that these VBOs can potentially contain millions of vertices, taking anywhere up to a couple of seconds to draw everything to the display. However, only a small fraction of the display would actually be updated each frame.

Is this optimisation possible, and how (or perhaps more appropriately, where) would this be implemented? Would some kind of clipping plane need to be passed into the vertex shader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set an area with `glViewport`, clipping is adjusted accordingly. This however happens after the vertex shader stage, just before rasterization. As the GL cannot know the result of your own vertex program, it cannot sort out any vertex before applying the vertex program. After that, it does. How efficent it does depents on the actual GPU.

Thus you have to sort and split your objects to smaller (eg. rectangulary bounded) tiles and test them against the field of view by yourself for full performance.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just to check - you are saying that simply adjusting the viewport will yield _some_ performance benefits; if I want the best optimisation I will need to check the bounds of each element and only draw those that fall within the dirty rectangle? Am I right in thinking that fragment shader might typically uses more computational power than the vertex shader? I'll test this, of course, but I wonder if you had an idea of the sort of gains I'd get from discarding 95% of the vertices in the clipping stage?

Comment: Adjusting the viewport eliminates most fragments to draw. However the GPU is meant to draw the whole screen at a decent framerate, thus that may not be your bottleneck if you are at "couple of seconds". Thus, setting the viewport is an easy but weak optimization. So I think you need to get rid of most the vertex processing at every redraw. You don't want to check millions of verticies by CPU either. So a simple solution would be slicing of your geometry to tiles by for example 64x64 pixels and draw only the touched ones.

Comment: Most of the time vertices are rendered (as 'brush' strokes) to texture and I easily get 60fps, however every now and then I will need to redraw strokes on a per-vertex basis and perform stencil testing. The "couple of seconds" only occurs when drawing a somewhat excessive (user-defind) number of vertices from the VBO, however I want to keep the performance at or above 20fps where possible. Tiling such data in this case is not trivial (different textures, variable sized VBOs... etc), however I'm sure that if clipping isn't sufficient, this will be. Thanks very much for the help.